# Fix all occurrences of similar warnings in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

In a php File I have a class, which methods do not have PHPDoc comments.

PhpStorm suggests that I add them. I do <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> on each one, and I was wondering if there were a way to bulk fix all similar warnings like these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the needed inspection (Code -> Run inspection by name -> i.e "Missing PHPDoc comment"), then in the "Inspections" tool window right-click on the inspection name and select quick fix, i.e "Generate PHPDoc comment".

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to run multiple inspections like "Missing @return" and "Missing comment" at once?